# How do I geta string of text that lies between two '{'parenthesis'}' set using .NET?

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a string `"Item Name {Item Code} {Item ID}"` and I want to extract the text between the first occurrence of `{}` i.e. `{Item Code}` ,
I used

> `Regex.Match( "Item Name {Item Code} {Item ID}", @"\{([^)]*)\}").Groups[0].Value`

but I got `"{Item Code} {Item ID}"`

How would I do this?

Comment: What if I wanted to search on the basis of three characters? for example "Item Name {Item;Code} {Item ID}". I wanted to search the pattern `{*;*}`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `{([^}]*)}`. Not a `)` in the character class, but a `}`. Meaning, match everything except (until) a `}`.

You may want to use `{([^{}]+)}` when you have input like `foo {bar {baz} not match {}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\{([^)]*?)\}")
```

make it lazy, it will work

IMHO use a regex like this: `\{(.*?)\}` your regex has a useless `[^)]`, the meaning of this along with `*` would be to select upto the `)` char, but there is no `)`. So, better off with my regex.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/eM6iL0

Comment: Why leave a useless `[^)]` in there? If using a lazy quantifier, you can write `{(.*?)}`.

Comment: Correct, but I prefer [this](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) tool when working with regex in C#. It offers more .Net specific options.

Comment: What if I wanted to search on the basis of three characters? for example `"Item Name {Item;Code} {Item ID}"`. I wanted to search the pattern `{*;*}`. How would I do this?

Comment: `\{\w+;\w+\}` should work in that case and dont forget the g modifier

Answer (score 0):

Using regex is better but since you tagged with `substring`, here is the way;

```
string s = "Item Name {Item Code} {Item ID}";
int index1 = s.IndexOf('{');
int index2 = s.IndexOf('}') ;
string result = s.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/RuBgJs)</kbd>.

[`IndexOf` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets the index of the first occurrence of specified character.